# Does SQL Server have something akin to "import" in Python?

Tags: sql-server

I have a couple of queries that do some actions that I want to be able to use in other, more complex queries.  Is it possible to reference/call/import a saved query in SQL Server?
In Python I would do something like "import coolcode" and then use that in my script.
Is there any way to do something similar in SQL Server so that I don't have to keep re-using that same query in all of the related queries?

Comment: No, there is no concept of modules or libraries in SQL.  If it's a query you're trying to reuse, you can create a View of it and use it (basically) the same as a table in other queries.

Comment: Views, functions, procedures...

Comment: Also CTEs and CLR functions. But no database has libraries like this.

Comment: The difference between what you are describing and what is being suggested here in these comments is that you are creating database objects for reuse. A view, for instance, is a sql statement that exists as an object in your database, just like a table. To use it, you select from it just like a table. Unlike a table it is just a sql statement that describes the result set, it holds no data of its own. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql

Comment: Most DBAs have some sort of utility database available, within this you can create all sorts of sharable objects such as functions, calendar and tally tables etc. Cross-database queries or use of synonyms can make utility functions easily consumable.